# Is there a way to force a javascript function to run first

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function on a page that dynamically changes the link for a nav item. Is there any way to guarantee this runs first before any other javascript besides it being the first on the page?

I'm asking because this is an important item and there is a possibility that in the future that something else might break before this script making this unable to run.

Comment: You can make it run here ... https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ ... of course if you have many `document.ready`s then it makes it almost impossible to track what is doing what ...

Comment: With vanilla js you could do it with window.onload instead of document.ready

Comment: @Exception_al I can't use jquery. It has to run before that's instantiated on the page.

Comment: javascript is run from top to bottom. if you have some form of a framework in place, you might be able to specify what runs first. the easiest course of action is to place the js as early as possible.

Comment: @Exception_al computers are predictable (thank god) if you can't figure out in which order things happen is always because of bad design and user error

Comment: @Mazz Would that insure that it loads before any other js on the page or just when the page loads?

Comment: @alebianco Exactly ... so neat code helps is what I was trying to imply ;) !

Comment: @castis Yes, I know that what's first on the page runs first. Just trying to see f there is a way around that.

Comment: @Exception_al I'm not the only developer. I'm trying to think of future developers that may break this.

Comment: You can only future proof it in that sense with good documentation and comments ... rest another developer, or even you for that matter, could by all means break or fix-the-fix so to say in the times to come !!!

Comment: If you don't control the other code, then this is simply impossible. If a script comes before yours, it will run before yours.

Comment: ...and jQuery surely won't add anything of value here.

Comment: ...but what do you mean by this: *"something else might break before this script making this unable to run."*

Comment: @squint Basicicly if someone else in the future puts code in before this that causes an error this won't run.

Comment: @zazvorniki: Is that other code in the same `<script>`? If not, yours will still run. If so, then it's just a matter of testing your code properly, and making the other person fix it.

Answer (score -2):

If the function is before in the code it will be executed before the rest as JS is a single threaded language. Problem might come that the DOM manipulation is not ready before the rest of the functions try to get the DOM items. That's the tricky part and hard to calculate and predict.

Easiest solution that comes to my mind is using a setTimeout checker with a flag or promises but it looks to me that maybe the approach to the problem should be rethink to not need setTimeouts at all. It's hard to be more precise with the actual code.

Comment: But I want to ensure that this happens before any other javasccript does. I have it first in the footer so it should appear after the page renders. 

Are you saying to put a set timeout on other javascript code? I'm trying to control what future developers put in.

Comment: If I'd want to do a DOM change on page load before everything else I would set a checker function (with small setInterval) for the change just after the DOM changing function which would enable the rest of the code to load. 

Afaik you can't rely on DOM changes to proceed on loading JS as it may vary from browser/device. Only checking when the change is ready with a flag might be a viable solution. You can present a loading screen to the user and fade it out when the flag changes to improve UX. 

But again I'd advise against using setTimeouts and try to rethink the approach.

Comment: But again, I'm not worried about the content being on the page before I change it. I am worried that someone might put code before this runs on the page that could have an error and could prevent this from running. I still don't understand where you are going with the settimeouts.

Comment: Then the only thing I can foresee to make your function not to be the first to load is that someone places code before. Be sure that your script file or inline JS is the one on top.